# pulling values from pointers in a loop

Tags: c, pointers

getLine is a function that gets a line, I'm trying to combine lines together outside the getLine function. When ever I try doing this in a loop it messes up the output. I bet it has to do with the pointers, but I have spend many hours trying to figure it out.

```
  int num;
  int matrix[370];

  i=1;
  j=0;
  while(*(point=getLine(infile)) != -2){ 
      n[j]=*point;
      if(n[0] != n[j]){
        printf("matrix dim error 1");
        break;
      }
      while (i<=n[j]){
        matrix[i+(3*j)] = *(point+(i+(3*j)));
        i++;
        printf("%d", matrix[i+(3*j)]);
      }
      printf("%d %d %d\n", matrix[1],matrix[2],matrix[3]);
      j++;
  }
  fclose( infile );
}

int *getLine(FILE *infile){

  int l=0;
  int line[7];
  int i=1;
  int *point;

  while ((l=getNum(infile)) != -1){
    if(l==EOF){
      line[0]=EOF;
      point = &line[0];
      return(point);
    }
    line[i]=l;
    i++;
  }
  if(i==1){
    line[0]=-2;
    point = &line[0];
    return(point);
  }
  line[0]=(i-1); //stores the length of the line in first space
  printf("%d %d %d\n",line[1],line[2],line[3]);
  point = &line[0];
  printf("%d\n",*point);
  return(point);
}

int getNum(FILE *infile) {
  int c=0;
  int value=0;


  while ((c=fgetc(infile)) != '\n') {
    if(c==EOF){
      return(EOF);
    }
    if((c==32)||(c==13)){
      if(value != 0){ //Making sure a number has been gotten
        //printf("%d\n\n", value);
        return(value);
      }
      //otherwise keep getting characters
    }
    else if ((c<=47)||(c>=58)){
      printf("incorrect number input %d\n", c);
      exit(1);
    }
    else {
      value = (10*value) + (c - '0');
    }
  }
  return(-1);//flags that the end of line has been hit
}
```

Comment: Show us the variable declarations, for pity's sake!

Comment: Could you please provide your code for declaring point and infile? And everything really

Comment: What's wrong with the output?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that `i` is not reset on each iteration of the outer loop, so its value increases continuously.

Comment: As I always tell to my quality department: logging a bug is not easy.  What's the output?  What should the output be according yourself?  What is the complete source/dataset/environment?

Comment: The output is large numbers not the simple integers I have in my input

Comment: Can you give examples for input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 3):

There is one problem:

```
int *getLine(FILE *infile){
    int line[7];
    int *point;

    point = &line[0];
    return(point);
}
```

You return a pointer to a local variable. It becomes invalid when you return from the function. You could allocate it instead on the heap, or let the caller provide it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while (i<=n[j]){
```

didn't you mean

```
while (i<=n[j][0]){
```

More Edit: That's actually ok, i overlook the * in the assignment.

Edit: Some more things:

- there is no check that the range of int is not exceeded in getNum
- there is no check in getLine that more than 7 values are read (which would blow int line[7]
- the matrix calculation in my opinion assumes that there are 3 values read, getLine can deliver up to 7
- matrix[i+(3*j)] = *(point+(i+(3*j)));  ?? point is only 7 int big!!! so for the second value it will read beyond defined data. Shouldn't it read matrix[i+(3*j)] = point[i];

hth

Mario

BTW: I strongly recommend:

- resort to std-lib functions
- better naming (i and j in the same source are strongly discouraged)